# "argument of type int is incompatible with parameter of type lpcwstr" in Visual Studio resource files

Tags: c++, resources

I'm trying to add a `.wav` file as a resource into my C++ game and play it on runtime. Here's my code in my main class:

```
PlaySound(IDR_WAVE1, GetModuleHandle(NULL), SND_FILENAME);
```

My `resource.h` file:

```
#define IDR_WAVE1                       104
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        105
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40001
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

And my `.rc` file:

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "winres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE
BEGIN
    "#include ""winres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (Australia) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENA)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_AUS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// WAVE
//

IDR_WAVE1 WAVE "C:\\Users\\zjf\\Desktop\\phil.wav"

#endif    // English (Australia) resources    
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

The issue is, I keep getting an error when trying to play this file from the resource.

> argument of type int is incompatible with parameter of type lpcwstr

I've included the `resource.h` header, and I've tried adding quotation marks in

```
PlaySound(IDR_WAVE1, GetModuleHandle(NULL), SND_FILENAME);
```

So it would end up being:

```
PlaySound("IDR_WAVE1", GetModuleHandle(NULL), SND_FILENAME);
```

However, this only made the Windows machine beep once.

I would appreciate any help, as I've never worked with resource files.

Comment: Have you tried to read [the documentation for `PlaySound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v%3Dvs.85))? It contains examples on how to use it, especially how to use it to play a sound from a resource ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
PlaySound(IDR_WAVE1, GetModuleHandle(NULL), SND_FILENAME);
```

change to:

```
PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_WAVE1), GetModuleHandle(NULL), SND_RESOURCE);
```